# MYSQL: I get multiple rows from exactly one row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, rows

So i'm trying to get a row of msg's of friends, but what i exactly got is multiple rows of one msg. So i did some research but i couldn't find anything about it only the opposite ways to do it.

Now i have a second problem after a user send me this query:

```
SELECT msg, userpost_ID, created, userone_ID, usertwo_ID, accepted 
FROM friendship, Posts 
WHERE friendship.userone_ID = '13' AND (Posts.userpost_ID = friendship.usertwo_ID OR Posts.userpost_ID = '13')
```

Now i have used the JOIN syntax but it displays the same problem here the query:

```
SELECT P.msg, P.userpost_ID, P.created,
   F.userone_ID, F.usertwo_ID, F.accepted, U.fname, U.lname FROM Posts P JOIN friendship F ON F.userone_ID = '13' JOIN Users U ON U.ID = F.usertwo_ID
```

[image]

Comment: Please post the SQL statement as text not as image

Comment: Sorry i saw it seconds after i posted it. I was searching for the query my fault!

Comment: You where statement is wrong. The last `OR` is incorrect, as now your query shows every post with `userpost_id ` 13

Comment: That's because i want to show the post of the user himself too.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add braces around the `OR`

```
SELECT 
   msg, 
   userpost_ID, 
   created, 
   userone_ID, 
   usertwo_ID, 
   accepted 
FROM 
   friendship, 
   Posts 
WHERE 
      friendship.userone_ID = '13'
  AND (Posts.userpost_ID = friendship.usertwo_ID 
  OR Posts.userpost_ID = '13')
```

Also use modern explizite join not implizit by using where

Answer (score 0):

You have had mistake in query just use below query to get accurate results OR simply add brackets in OR condition

```
SELECT 
   msg, 
   userpost_ID, 
   created, 
   userone_ID, 
   usertwo_ID, 
   accepted 
FROM 
   friendship, 
   Posts 
WHERE 
   friendship.userone_ID = '13'
   AND (Posts.userpost_ID = friendship.usertwo_ID 
   OR Posts.userpost_ID = '13')
```

Hope this will help you!!

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Look to my edit now i'm getting a second problem. It still rows multiple messages from one message from id 13.

Answer (score 0):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  That would pretty much fix your problem:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM friendship f JOIN
     Posts p
     ON p.userpost_ID = f.usertwo_ID 
WHERE f.userone_ID = 13;
```

Notes:

- You only need `p.userpost_ID = 13` if you want the user's messages as well.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- You should qualify all column names (specify the table where they come from).

Comment: Sorry but i never used the JOIN syntax, where do i need to put the syntax? If i want to used it.